# Access Point (AP) and use of cell at the same time

Tags: wifi

I would like to be able to have my RPi 0 W be an Access Point (AP) and my cell phone be able to use cell data services so I can use my Pi in my car and not have a secondary device.  I can’t use maps or any other app I use while on a trip and attached to the AP.
I have followed this guide:
http://www.raspberryconnect.com/network/item/327-raspberry-pi-auto-wifi-hotspot-switch 
Using the Zero W parameters. By the way, this page is a great resource.  My Pi’s AP has worked for over two years.
I also have this device in my car http://www.obdlink.com/mxwf/
This device claims to use a “softAP” and with it I can use maps and read the device information.

I have searched for this request on various sites for many years.  I don’t know if I am asking the wrong questions for my search, is this even possible, or am I just too dumb?  I would love to have help because other AP users with cars might want the same information.  I am using the most current iOS on my phone.

Thanks.

Comment: "I would like to be able to have my RPi 0 W be an Access Point (AP) and my cell phone be able to use cell data services so I can use my Pi in my car and not have a secondary device." is subject to several interpretations and will, at best, invite speculative answers to what interpretation the respondent assumes.

Comment: i have read your description of what you are trying to do several times and it makes absolutely no sense ... it seems that you have left out some important information ...... how do the RPi and the cell phone interact? .... what would be the purpose of the "secondary device" if you had one? ..... please draw a block diagram of the system that you are designing ...... how is the fact that the AP has worked for 2 years relevant to your question?